# Cambiar estilo botones toolbar fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

Tengo un problema, estoy utilizando fullcalendar y necesito cambiar el estilo de los botones del toolbar, mas especificamente el estilo cuando se le da un click a estos botones ya que al hacerlo se marca un borde gris y necesito cambiar ese comportamiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo se lo agradecería un montón

Comment: Seria bueno saber que fullcalendar esta utilizando y mejor aún que agregaras un [mcve].